# Should I cache FastAPI dependency?

Tags: fastapi

In my app I am planning to have a way to build dependencies dynamically as follows:

```
def authorized_to(result):

    def dependency(
            r=Depends(result),
            token: Token = Depends(make_current_token_dep(auth_any))
    ):
        if r is True:
            return token

        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN, detail="Action not allowed"
        )

    return Depends(dependency)
```

Question is, given that the dependency is a function defined within a function, is it a good idea to let FastAPI automatically cache it or should I disable caching for this dependency?

Comment: What is your goal by caching dependencies by wrapping them in another dependency? FastAPI will only evaluate a dependency once for a request already, so even if you have multiple dependencies that depend on the same function, it will only be evaluated once.

Comment: My goal is to build a small authorization system for my app. I would like the user to be able to add a dependency such as `token = authorized_to(perform_action)` where `perform_action` is another user-defined function that can get to choose its own dependencies. I am asking this question because I am returning an inner function (`def dependency`) and I suspect that FastAPI may infinitely cache this function or maybe return stale versions from cache.